# Erro ao converter HTML para PDF

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

Preciso fazer um PDF a partir de uma página `HTML`, porém ao converter recebo o seguinte erro:

> Não é possível converter um objeto do tipo 'iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.TableWrapper' no tipo 'iTextSharp.text.Meta'.

Segue o código:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="PaginaQueSeraConvertida.aspx.cs" Inherits="converterHTMLparaPDF.PaginaQueSeraConvertida" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

  Exportação de ASPX para PDF

        <span id="export" runat="server"></span>


 </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
using System;

using System.Collections;

using System.Configuration;

using System.Data;

using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.html;
using iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser;
using System.Text;



namespace converterHTMLparaPDF
{
    public partial class PaginaQueSeraConvertida : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            criatabela();
            ConverteAspx2Pdf();
        }

        private void criatabela()
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("<table width='95%' border='0'><tr><td width='8%' class='tblNormal' align='Right'>Protocolo:</td>");
            sb.Append("<td width='8%' class='tblNormal' align='Right'>Devedor:</td>");
            sb.Append("<td width='16%' class='tblNormal' align='Right'>CNPJ/CPF:</td>");
            sb.Append("</tr><tr>");
            sb.Append("<td class='tblNormal' align='Right'>Título:</td>");
            sb.Append("<td class='tblNormal' align='Right'>Apresentante:</td>");
            sb.Append("<td class='tblNormal' align='Right'>Data Vencimento:</td>");
            sb.Append("</tr><tr>");
            sb.Append("<td class='tblNormal' align='Right'>Valor:</td>");
            sb.Append("<td class='tblNormal' align='Right'>Saldo:</td>");
            sb.Append("<td class='tblNormal' align='Right'>Data apontamento:</td>");
            sb.Append("</tr><tr>");
            sb.Append("<td class='tblNormal' align='Right'>Livro:</td>");
            sb.Append("<td class='tblNormal' align='Right'>Folha:</td>");
            sb.Append("<td class='tblNormal' align='Right'>Data protesto:</td>");
            sb.Append("</tr><tr>");
            export.InnerHtml = sb.ToString();
        }


        private void ConverteAspx2Pdf()
        {

            string attachment = "inline; filename=ExportacaoAspx2Pdf.pdf";

            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

            StringWriter stw = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter htextw = new HtmlTextWriter(stw);

            this.RenderControl(htextw);

            Document document = new Document();
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, Response.OutputStream);

            document.Open();

            StringReader str = new StringReader(stw.ToString());
            HTMLWorker htmlworker = new HTMLWorker(document);

            htmlworker.Parse(str);
            document.Close();
            Response.Write(document);
            Response.End();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sua aplicação chegar a entrar no método ConverteAspx2Pdf()

Comment: Sim! Coloquei exatamente o que esta na aplicação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu `HTML` esta faltando a tag de fechamento .

Veja abaixo

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser;

namespace WebApplication1tiraduvidas
{
    public partial class PaginaQueSeraConvertida : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            criatabela();
            ConverteAspx2Pdf();
        }

        private void criatabela()
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("<table width='95%' border='0'><tr><td width='8%' >Protocolo:</td>");
            sb.Append("<td width='8%' >Devedor:</td>");
            sb.Append("<td width='16%' >CNPJ/CPF:</td>");
            sb.Append("</tr><tr>");
            sb.Append("<td>Título:</td>");
            sb.Append("<td >Apresentante:</td>");
            sb.Append("<td >Data Vencimento:</td>");
            sb.Append("</tr><tr>");
            sb.Append("<td >Valor:</td>");
            sb.Append("<td >Saldo:</td>");
            sb.Append("<td >Data apontamento:</td>");
            sb.Append("</tr><tr>");
            sb.Append("<td >Livro:</td>");
            sb.Append("<td >Folha:</td>");
            sb.Append("<td >Data protesto:</td>");
            sb.Append("</tr></table>");
            Principal.InnerHtml = sb.ToString();
        }

        public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
        {
        }

        private void ConverteAspx2Pdf()
        {
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=TestPage.pdf");
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            this.Page.RenderControl(hw);
            StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
            Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);
            HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
            pdfDoc.Open();
            htmlparser.Parse(sr);
            pdfDoc.Close();
            Response.Write(pdfDoc);
            Response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

Também use o método:

```
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
            {
            }
```

e no aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" EnableEventValidation="false" CodeBehind="PaginaQueSeraConvertida.aspx.cs"
  Inherits="WebApplication1tiraduvidas.PaginaQueSeraConvertida" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div id="Principal" runat="server">
    Exportação de ASPX para PDF
  </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Excelente exemplo. Agora só preciso centralizar o conteudo no meio da página. Pois ao criar o PDF ele não reduzio para caber na página

Comment: Bom ai vc vai ter que usar um pouco de css , caso precise alterar o pdf mesmo vc pode alterar a linha  `Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);`  diminuindo as margens do documento .

Comment: existe alguma maneira de salvar esse arquivo gerado dentro do sevidor? Sem a necessidade de abrí-lo para o cliente e  sem abrir a janela de download?

Comment: Sim... Veja o link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31078442/how-to-save-pdf-on-server-map-path-using-itextsharp]

Answer (score 1):

`HTMLWorker' está [deprecated](http://itext.2136553.n4.nabble.com/iText-PDF-using-HTML-Worker-issue-td4655474.html) a sugestão agora é usar [XMLWorker](http://api.itextpdf.com/xml/)

Segue um exemplo simples da utilização dele:

```js
StringReader html = new StringReader(@"
<div style='font-size: 18pt; font-weight: bold;'>
Mouser Electronics <br />Authorized Distributor</div><br /> <br />
<div style='font-size: 14pt;'>Click to View Pricing, Inventory, Delivery & Lifecycle Information:
</div>
<br />
<div>
<table>
<tr><td></td><td>
<a href='http://www.mouser.com/access/?pn=78211-009' 
style='color: Blue; font-size: 10pt; text-decoration: underline;'>78211-009</a></td></tr>
</table></div>    
");      
using (Document document = new Document()) {
  PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, STREAM);
  document.Open();
  XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(
    writer, document, html
  );
}
```

Uma observação é que para usar `XMLWorker` você precisa do seu `HTML` bem formatado, todas as tags fechadas corretamente.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Esse componente não é do Java?

Comment: Existe ele também para c#, é essa DLL que você referencia no seu código. Aqui tem um bom texto sobre como usar. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25164257/how-to-convert-html-to-pdf-using-itextsharp

Comment: Olha no código dele: `iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper`

Comment: Ele não reconhece esse namespace!

Comment: Você está com a versão mais atual? https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp/

Comment: Sim estou. Mas na dúvida desinstalei e instalei novamente e o erro persiste.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31228/discussion-between-germano-sampaio-and-user3517631).